# How do I make a horizontal navbar using CSS, that supports hover and respects the edges of the container?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to make a CSS based nav bar that converts a UL/LI list (including sub UL/LI lists that display on hover) into a horizontal nav bar and a sub horizontal nav bar.  My current implementation (see picture) works except the sub list is using position:absolute to get its position below the hovered element.  I believe that is the source of my problem, as the absolute positioned sub menu doesnt respect the edges of the container, so if the browser gets too small it bleeds off the edge of the container while the top level menu wraps.  The other problem i'm having is that it doesnt expand the page vertically when the top level menu wraps, so even though its taking up more space the paragraph following doesnt move down and gets overlapped.

Does anybody have any CSS tips or know of any good examples of a menu like the one I'm trying to make?

Link to image:
http://i47.tinypic.com/288tbn7.png

Comment: If you don't care about animation, you can put the submenu inside the `<li>` and set `display:none` on it; then you can use `li.menu:hover .submenu { display: inline-block; }` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this day, the article "Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns" by HTML Dog is still a classic on clean CSS menus with hover.

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: Seems to be very similar to what I have, the problem is with a horizontal sub menu absolute positioning has the overlapping flaw I described.  Its kind of a silly looking menu, but it's what was requested.

Comment: You could try to position the submenus with `position: relative`, since this won't remove the elements from the document flow, instead of `position: absolute`. I think the only reason why people use absolute positioning for this is they actually WANT it to overlap the page content directly below.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now create this menu easily used to `ul li` simply as like this

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home3</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
    .menu{
display:block;
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom:solid 1px red;
  float:left;
}
.menu > li{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.menu > li + li{
  border-left:solid 1px red;
margin-left:10px;
}
.menu > li > a{
display:block;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.submenu{
  display:none;
list-style:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-39px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu{
display:block;
}
.submenu li{
display:inline;
}
.submenu li + li {
border-left:1px solid green;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.submenu a{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/SpnWLiEl)

and now change **css** `according to your layout` this is **basic step**